# ASP.NET MVC create models in fast way by Entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6.1 in Database First approach.

I starting create Models Class response to each Entity (the tables of database),
I feel it is boring task and found that Entity Framework almost done for me.

I expand the *.edmx file and then expand *.tt file, there are many class there and 90% similar to my hand made models.
[image]

So I start search on Google to see what is the best practice to generate models in smart way. Finally, the following 2 ways I found.

**1.** Copy all the class corresponding to each database's table to Models folder and remove this line:

```
System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
```

**2.** Using EF 6.1 Wizard - Code First from Database
Which similar to method 1 but come with addition DataAnnotations. 
[image]

There is a 3rd method [recommended by Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application),
Generate the Context with Models inside Models folder and work with, the most simple way, but we know this is the worst one.

So Which method I mention above is proper way to create models?

Answer (score 0):

Data base First approach is the best way to create model classes but u don't want annotations for model class at this time you may  select 'EF Designer from Database' option from EF wizard choose model step